# I want to give a string a value of one

Tags: c++

I'm entering team names into a soccer league.

I have an array set up so that the league can take at most 4 teams,

I also have an array that states that the number of teams in the league is exactly 4 teams.

So I want to set up a counter which stops me from entering too many team names.

This is a small chunk of my code

str teamName

```
for(int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++)

cout << "Enter a Team Name"<<endl'
cin >> teamName;
```

so is there a way for me to give a team name a value of 1 so that each time I enter a team name it decrements the number in the array until I can't add any more teams?

I am new at c++ and haven't been learning for that long so I might be totally off here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so in other words I won't have the option to enter another team reguardless right? That means in my code I don't need to put anything after my cin statement?

Comment: isn't you for-loop already counting to max leagueSize = 4? So in the end you will only be asked 4 times? Can you give more information? When and where does it go wrong? 

By the way, give your for-loop brackets as it will now only take the first line. so for(){ cout << ... << endl; cin >> teamname; }

Comment: That is what I'm saying based on what I see here yes. Every time "cin >> teamName" is called you will be asked to fill in a name. As it is only asked 4 times, only 4 teams can be passed as far as I can see from this code.

Comment: Aside: Instead of using an array, learn about the standard template library vector class (which is more flexible and safer than an array):  
#include <vector>
vector<string> teamName;
teamName.push_back( aTeam );
teamName.push_back( anotherTeam );

Answer (score 4):

You're almost there, you are just missing some curly braces, and you need to declare an array instead of a single string for the team names:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
 int leagueSize = 4;
 string teamNames[leagueSize];
 for (int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++) {
  cout << "Enter a team name:" << endl;
  cin >> teamNames[i];
 }

 cout << endl;
 cout << "The following teams have been entered:" << endl;
 for (int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++) {
  cout << "Team " << (i + 1) << ": " << teamNames[i] << endl;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A for controls structure (as well as if, else and while), executes the next single statement or block.  So in your example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++)
    cout << "Enter a Team Name"<<endl;
cin >> teamName;
```

Only the output statement is part of the for loop and the input statement happens only once after the entire loop is finished.

So, what you want to do is put your code in a block:

```
for(int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++)
{
    cout << "Enter a Team Name"<<endl;
    cin >> teamName;
}
```

Many C and C++ coding styles recommend you always use a block even if you only have a single statement:

```
for (...)
{
    one-statement;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I've edited the code a bit,

The exact instructions say:
write a function to enter all the team names and set all the other variables

So its ok for me to do all that in one function isn't it?

This is the full function that I've come up with
void addTeam(T *T, char *teamName, int i)
{
    str teamName[leagueSize];

```
for(int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++)

{
cout << "Enter a Team Name"<<endl'
cin >> teamName[i]; 
}

cout << endl;
cout << "The following teams have been entered:" << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < leagueSize; i++) {
cout << "Team " << (i + 1) << ": " << teamNames[i] << endl;


T[i].name = teamName;
T[i].numPoints = 0;
T[i].numGoalsFor = 0;
T[i].numGoalsAgainst = 0;
T[i].numMatchesPlayed = 0;
T[i].numMatchesWon = 0;
T[i].numMatchesLost = 0;
T[i].numMatchesDrawn = 0;
```

}

Comment: You shouldn't reply to your question with a new question - how would I know to read it? But to answer your question - yes that's OK, although it would be much better to put the initialization of the Team members into the Team class constructor. That's what the constructor is for.